# Create shortcut to newest file matching pattern

Tags: windows, batch-file, shortcuts

Whenever I donload new versions of an app under development, they are labeled like

```
C:\Users\...\Downloads\twinBASIC_IDE_BETA_{123}\twinBASIC.exe
```

Where {123} is some release number (incrementing integer)

Can I make a shortcut that when I double click it opens the version of this file with the greatest version number/ most recent download or creation date? I could write a VBS script to do this but I'd rather just put something in the shortcut itself. Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you just rename the archive and replace the previous version with the current version? I am making an assumption that you downloaded an archive file, which was named `twinBASIC_IDE_BETA_{123}` and could simply name it `twinBASIC_IDE_BETA` and extract it to the same folder everytime.

Comment: That's a good idea actually. I suppose the former is still marginally more convenient, I just download and unzip, no typing necessary+ I retain the number in the folder path in case there is a bug and I need to create an issue referencing it... This is just a convenience.

Comment: Additionally, this is not a script writing service. We'd appreciate it if you'd tell us what you've tried, the research you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Version name layout `IDE_BETA_+'nnn'`

```bath
%ComSpec% /v /r "for /L %L in (999 -1 1)do if exist "%Userprofile%\Downloads\twinBASIC_IDE_BETA_%~L\." (cd /d "%Userprofile%\Downloads\twinBASIC_IDE_BETA_%~L" && start "" /b "!cd!\twinBASIC.exe" && exit /b)"
```

- List by creation date in reverse order:

```bath
%ComSpec% /v /r "for /f delims^=* %i in ('dir /b /s /a:d /o-d "%Userprofile%\Downloads\twinBASIC_IDE_BETA_*"')do if exist "%~dpnxi\twinBASIC.exe" (cd /d "%~dpnxi" && start "" /b "!cd!\twinBASIC.exe" && exit /b)"
```

Comment: That is _really_ cool. Especially if I change the shortcut to run minimised.